# Матрица в DataGrid и SQLite WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

Имеется таблица в SQLite типа:
строка столбец значение
1-------------1------------2
2-------------1------------5

и т.д.
Таким образом получается, что в строке 1 и столбце 1 DataGrid должно находиться значение 2, в строке 2, столбце 1 значение 5.
Как это можно реализовать (пример ниже) или направьте где почитать?
Я знаю, что у DataGrid есть свойство ItemSource в Columns и Rows.
При этом должны занулиться все остальные ячейки, у которых значение не равно 1.

Как можно заполнить DataGrid 1 в 1 из SQLite я разобрался, но как по известным строкам и столбцам не могу понять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совсем понятно какая именно часть вызывается проблемы с реализацией

Comment: Отредактировал первое сообщение

Answer (score 0):

Берете свой ридер, каждая строка это отдельная сущность, запечатываете в `ObservableCollection<>` и "подсовываете" в `DataGrid`. А еще почитайте про Binding, ООП и MVVM.

Comment: Про Binding читал, сейчас с ним пытаюсь работать, также как и с ObservableCollection<> и SQLiteDataReader. А по MVVM, боюсь за него браться, т.к. придётся переделывать все то, что уже есть сейчас.

Comment: Получается, если у меня будет 100 строк, то будет 100 сущностей?